# GROUP BY Date of DateTime Data Type

Tags: ms-access

I have data like this :

```
    CHECKTIME       
02/03/2020 6:54:50  
02/03/2020 8:00:00  
02/03/2020 16:34:37 
03/03/2020 8:02:41  
03/03/2020 16:45:00 
03/03/2020 16:45:03 
04/03/2020 7:57:46  
04/03/2020 7:57:48  
04/03/2020 17:01:53 
04/03/2020 17:01:56 
05/03/2020 8:03:45  
05/03/2020 8:03:48  
05/03/2020 16:41:02
```

I want above data to group by date but ordered by date and time without crop the time part out. So the result would be like this:

```
    CHECKTIME       
02/03/2020 6:54:50
03/03/2020 8:02:41
04/03/2020 7:57:46
05/03/2020 8:03:45
```

Can i achieve this result?

I have searched for about a week from forum one to another but unfortunately the question similar with this only asking about group datetime by date and show date part only without maintain the time part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the minimum `CHECKTIME` for each of the dates which you can get with the function [`DATEVALUE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f):

```
SELECT MIN(CHECKTIME) 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY DATEVALUE(CHECKTIME)
```

Another solution with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tablename AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename
  WHERE DATEVALUE(CHECKTIME) = DATEVALUE(t.CHECKTIME) AND CHECKTIME < t.CHECKTIME
)
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I didn't know that we can use `DateValue()` function which is different with the selected function. Is it because `MIIN()` is an aggregate function while `DateValue` is not ?

Comment: DATEVALUE() is used to return the date part only from the column CHECKTIME and this  result (the date only without the time)  is used in the GROUP BY clause. So you get the minimum CHECKTIME for each date.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir. I just didn't know we can group by like that (`Group By DateValue(CHECKTIME)`) which is not one of SELECT lists

Comment: The expression that you use in the GROUP BY clause can be omitted from the SELECT list if it's not needed. But it is not allowed to use columns in the SELECT list that are not aggregated and are included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I see. So i only could do `Group By` expression like this case if the `SELECT` list is aggregate function, otherwise (not aggregate function) wouldn't be allowed.
Thanks for the extra solution sir.

Answer (score 0):

you can just group by checktime casted to date

```sql
select CHECKTIME from table_name group by timestamp::date
```

this syntax is valid in postgreSQL database

Comment: I don't understand your query. By the way CHECKTIME is a field_name not table_name and also we can't group like that in Ms Access, we should include all of selected field_name  as `group by` parameters.